# Substitute all characters between two strings by char 'X' using sed

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, sed

In a Bash script, I am trying to in-file replace the characters between two given strings by 'X'. I have bunch of string pair, between which I want the replacement of characters by 'X' should happen.
In the below code, the **first** string in the pair is declared in **cpi_list** array. The **second** string in the pair is always either **`%26` or `&` or `ENDOFLINE`**

This is what I am doing.

```
# list of "first" or "start" string
declare -a cpi_list=('%26Name%3d' '%26Pwd%3d')  

# This is the "end" string
myAnd=\%26
newfile="inputlog.txt"

for item in "${cpi_list[@]}";
do
    sed -i -e :a -e "s/\($item[X]*\)[^X]\(.*"$myAnd"\)/\1X\2/;ta" $newfile;
done
```

The input

```
CPI.%26Name%3dJASON%26Pwd%3dBOTTLE%26Name%3dCOTT
CPI.%26Name%3dVoorhees&machete
```

I want to make it

```
CPI.%26Name%3dXXXXX%26Pwd%3dXXXXXX%26Name%3dXXXX
CPI.%26Name%3dXXXXXXXX&machete
```

PS: The last item need also change `%26Name%3dCOTT` to `%26Name%3dXXXX` even though there is no end `%26` because I am looking for either `%26` as the end point or the `END OF THE LINE`

But somehow it is not working.

Comment: What result *are* you getting?

Comment: %3dCOTT because it is between %26Name%3d and the end of the line.

Comment: @chepner This the result I am getting `CPI.%26Name%3dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26Name%3dCOTT`

Comment: @anubhava END OF THE LINE is not very important, i can live without it too... good to have it but not so critical.. but the other part is important.. if you can give the solution, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicates of the following posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885198/replace-all-characters-between-two-strings-in-a-line-by-x https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864172/bash-script-in-file-replace-characters-with-x-between-two-given-strings-usin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911200/change-string-in-file-between-two-strings-with-character-x

Comment: Yeh @alvits... I was asked to raise it as a separate question..

Comment: How many times is [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944021/sed-substitude-all-characters-between-two-strings-by-char-x#comment71073884_41944021) going to be asked?

Comment: Because @sorontar if you noticed the last post, it was not perfactly answered. So i had to ask again.

Comment: The problem you had previously is that you hadn't tagged your question with awk, only sed. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines. What you're trying to do is not that so you should be looking for an awk solution, not a sed one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work in any awk called from any shell in any UNIX installation:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    begs = "%26Name%3d|%26Pwd%3d"
    ends = "%26|&"
}
{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while( match(tail, begs) ) {
        tgtStart = RSTART + RLENGTH
        tgt = substr(tail,tgtStart)
        if ( match(tgt, ends) ) {
            tgt = substr(tgt,1,RSTART-1)
        }

        gsub(/./,"X",tgt)
        head = head substr(tail,1,tgtStart-1) tgt
        tail = substr(tail,tgtStart+length(tgt))
    }
    $0 = head tail

    print
}

$ cat file
CPI.%26Name%3dJASON%26Pwd%3dBOTTLE%26Name%3dCOTT
CPI.%26Name%3dVoorhees&machete

$ awk -f tst.awk file
CPI.%26Name%3dXXXXX%26Pwd%3dXXXXXX%26Name%3dXXXX
CPI.%26Name%3dXXXXXXXX&machete
```

Just like with a sed subsitution, any regexp metacharacter in the beg and end strings would need to be escaped or we'd have to use a loop with `index()`s instead of `match()` so we'd do string matching instead of regexp matching.

Comment: I am closing this post and marking your answer as the final answer.. however one thing thats pitching my mind is, can this be done infile? instead of "print" and writing the output back to the original file? just asking.

Comment: With GNU awk you can add the `-i infile` argument but why bother when you can just do `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file` for any command including `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`. There's no "instead of print" though - you still need the print either way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not *pretty* but you can use perl:

```
$ s1="CPI.%26Name%3dJASON%26Pwd%3dBOTTLE%26Name%3dCOTT"
$ echo "$s1" | perl -lne 'if (/(?:^.*%26Name%3d)(.*)(?:%26Pwd%3d)(?:.*%26Name%3d)(.*)((?:%26Pwd%3d)|(?:$))/) { 
        $i1=$-[1];
        $l1=$+[1]-$-[1];
        $i2=$-[2];
        $l2=$+[2]-$-[2];
        substr($_, $i1, $l1, "X"x$l1);
        substr($_, $i2, $l2, "X"x$l2);
        print;
        }'
CPI.%26Name%3dXXXXX%26Pwd%3dBOTTLE%26Name%3dXXXX
```

That is for two pairs like the example. N pairs in a line will be a slight modification.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to do it in bash script. Not perl.

Comment: Why do you "have" to do it in `bash`?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `%26` doing this:

```
a='CPI.%26Name%3dJASON%26Pwd%3dBOTTLE%26Name%3dCOTT'
echo "$a" |sed -E ':a;s/(%3dX*)([^%X]|%[013-9a-f][0-9a-f]|%2[0-5789a-f])/\1X/g;ta;'
```

Note that each encoded character `%xx` counts for one X.

Comment: GNU sed only. POSIX it would need a change.

Comment: @dawg: something like this I suppose: `sed -e 's/%26/\&/g;' -e :a -e 's/\(%3d[^&]*\)[^&X]/\1X/g;ta;s/&/%26/g;'` (I only use GNU sed)

Comment: That doesn't work because the pattern space `a`  is scoped locally to each `-e`

Comment: This will not work, because the inputlog.txt file i have, each line can have many '&' at different places... So I cannot replace %26 with & and vice-versa.

Comment: @PuneetJain: choose an other character.

Comment: No @CasimiretHippolyte. Because the input log file i have is very huge.. and I am pretty sure, the file and each lines will have all most all the characters.... Each file has a huge line... almost like 80K words in each line..etc..

Comment: @PuneetJain: Try this other approach without to substitute `%26`: `sed -E ':a;s/(%3dX*)([^%X]|%[013-9a-f][0-9a-f]|%2[0-5789a-f])/\1X/g;ta'` (note that the advantage is that each `%xx` code is replaced by only one X since it represents only one character.). You can also use: `sed -E ':a;s/(%3dX*)[^%]/\1X/g;ta'` but it doesn't deal with eventual `%xx` other than `%26`.

Comment: That will not work either.. because we need to see how many characters were replaced. Lets say, client sent Pwd as PASSWORD. So we will replace it with XXXXXXXX and not with X because this way we will know that the client sent 8 characters in the password.. Pwd is just one field, there are other types of data too like Zipcode, cardnumber, socialsecurity, pin, lastname, maidenname etc etc etc

Comment: @PuneetJain: you need to understand that what you are trying to hide is encoded. For example if your client gives `a#b` as password, the result in your log will be: `a%23b`